# How do I find the fourier transform of the following function?

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-transform, signal-processing

$$
x(t) = te^{-\alpha t}cos(\beta t)
$$

I was not able to find $$te^{-\alpha t}$$ inside one of the Fourier tables.

I am not even sure where to begin. Do I have to begin from first principals?

Comment: What table are you using, this is defined in good ones. [107 here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_transform#Functional_relationships,_one-dimensional)

Answer (score 1):

$$ f(t) = te^{-at} u(t) $$

$$ F(w) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi} (a+jw)^2} $$

Advanced Engineering Mathematics
KA Stroud, Fourth Edition